Why @font-face with local() src is not working?
I'm trying to implement a fallback font for better webpage performance. For this I tried to make use of src: local(Arial) and redefining the ascent-override, descent-override and size-adjust properties (this should reduce the page's CLS)
However, when trying to see if the fallback works, I notice that this font is not applied.
Can anybody explain what's the problem with this?
For declaring I use the following code:
@font-face {
    font-family: "Inter Fallback";
    font-style: normal;
    src: local(Arial);
    ascent-override: 90.199%;
    descent-override: 22.4836%;
    size-adjust: 107.4014%;
    font-weight: 100 900;
    font-display: swap;
}

And use it by the following rule:
body {
    font-family: "Inter", "Inter Fallback", Arial, sans-serif;
}

When I try to replace the local(Arial) with the url(), this seems to perform well.
P.S. It also doesn't work with using the local("Arial") or specifying any of the other default fonts (e.g. Times New Roman)

local() is not very reliable. Frankly it works pretty fine at least on chromium/Firefox. Not sure what you expect. The fallback font won't improve your CLS ratings as most likely the browser will first try to render the desired font – you may try to host the font locally and preload it to optimize the loading times

@herrstrietzel, The font is already hosted locally, but nevertheless, there is a significant gap between the "Inter" and other fallback fonts. That's why the decision is to adjust the ascent-override, descent-override, and size-adjust properties to make Arial letters match "Inter" by size, spacing, etc.

Better focus on the inter loading itself e.g by removing unused variable axes (for instance opsz). Most browsers won't render the Inter-fallback first and then replace it with the proper one. In other words the browser doesn't know the fall-back font-face should be preferred on initial rendering (to avoid layout shifts)
